# Lock background in place behind a modal

Tags: jquery, css

I'm creating a simple modal. When the modal is shown I want the modal to show at the top of the page and the background to be locked so only the modal scrolls.

On modal show I'm setting the background to `position:fixed` but its scrolling it to the top before fixing.

Also, if scrolling half way down a page before clicking to show modal, the modal is scrolled down too when opened.

**What I want to happen is:** wherever a user is on the page, click to open modal and lock background there. Then only scroll modal. then close modal and all returns to where it was.

Is this possible?

[Here's a fiddle showing all the code](http://jsfiddle.net/darrensw/dBXyL/7/)

This is the css I'm trying:

```
.modBG { /* background */
position:fixed;
top:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
right:0;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
z-index:15;
display:none;
height:100%;
width:100%;
}

#wishData { /* modal window */
width:100px;
z-index:20;
position:absolute;
display:none;
margin:0 auto;
min-height:60px;
overflow-y:auto;
overflow-x:hidden;
padding:10px;
background:#fff;
top:20px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 14px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
box-shadow:         0px 0px 14px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
margin-left:100px;
}
```

And the jquery:

```
$(document).on('click', '.wishView', function() {
    $('#sb-site').css('position','fixed');
    $('.modBG').show();
    $('#wishData').show();
    return false;
});

// click background to close modal
$(document).on('click', '.modBG', function() {
        $('.modBG').hide();
        $('#wishData').hide();
        $('#sb-site').css('position','relative');
    });
```

Comment: Why don't you try a fixed height for the popup with overflow scroll ? with no position fixed on the background, would that be ok ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Thanks for the answers/comments.

[Here's how I did it](http://jsfiddle.net/darrensw/dBXyL/25/)

Wrapped the modal in another element then applied `overflow:hidden` to body & html

```
$(document).on('click', '.wishView', function() {
    var winheight = $(window).height();
    $('.modHolder').css('min-height',winheight);
    $('body').addClass('noScroll');
    $('.modBG, .modHolder, #wishData').show();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

Set the modal to a max-height to something like 90%

and set overflow-y:scroll; on the modal container as well

When the modal loads then set the

```
body{overflow:hidden;}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dBXyL/12/

Edit: added new fiddle with position fixed on the modal container.

Comment: No thats not a good solution unfortunately, also, scroll down to link to and most of its hidden when clicked

Comment: Then set the max-height to something like 70% then it wont